# BCP and BULK INSERT fails to throw error for incomplete records in fixed width file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert, bcp

I am attempting to insert a file utilizing either bulk insert or bcp. The file is a fixed width file that has rows with far fewer columns (positions) than the format file specifies.  When executing either statement, these rows are excluded, but the process does not error out.

The file contains 42 records. Three records are incomplete (Field lengths are only several hundred positions out of a possible 6000 positions). I am expecting all 42 records to be attempted, and ultimately, expect the process to error out due to the 3 incomplete records. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

The following queries execute with the following message: '(39 row(s) affected)'

BULK INSERT:

```
BULK INSERT ##tmp_table
FROM '\\cf\files\file_1_20131223.txt' 
WITH (FIRSTROW = 1, MAXERRORS = 0, FORMATFILE = '\\cf\bcpFiles\file_1.fmt')
```

BCP:

```
DECLARE @cmdLoad VARCHAR(2000)

SET @cmdLoad = 'bcp ##tmp_table IN "\\cf\files\file_1_20131223.txt" -F 1' 
+ ' -f "\\cf\bcpFiles\file_1.fmt -m 0 -T -S cf_db'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmdLoad
```

The format file looks like:

```
10.0
123
1         SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     1       Field1              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2         SQLCHAR       0    20       ""     2       Field2              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3         SQLCHAR       0    20       ""     3       Field3              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4         SQLCHAR       0    2        ""     4       Field4              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5         SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     5       Field5              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6         SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     6       Field6              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7         SQLCHAR       0    15       ""     7       Field7              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8         SQLCHAR       0    15       ""     8       Field8              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
9         SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     9       Field9              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
10        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     10      Field10             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
11        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     11      Field11             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
12        SQLCHAR       0    9        ""     12      Field12             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
13        SQLCHAR       0    4        ""     13      Field13             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
14        SQLCHAR       0    48       ""     14      Field14             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
15        SQLCHAR       0    320      ""     15      Field15             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
16        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     16      Field16             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
17        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     17      Field17             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
18        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     18      Field18             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
19        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     19      Field19             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
20        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     20      Field20             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
21        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     21      Field21             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
22        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     22      Field22             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
23        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     23      Field23             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
24        SQLCHAR       0    24       ""     24      Field24             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
25        SQLCHAR       0    24       ""     25      Field25             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
26        SQLCHAR       0    18       ""     26      Field26             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
27        SQLCHAR       0    24       ""     27      Field27             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
28        SQLCHAR       0    14       ""     28      Field28             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
29        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     29      Field29             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
30        SQLCHAR       0    20       ""     30      Field30             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
31        SQLCHAR       0    3        ""     31      Field31             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
32        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     32      Field32             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
33        SQLCHAR       0    20       ""     33      Field33             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
34        SQLCHAR       0    3        ""     34      Field34             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
35        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     35      Field35             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
36        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     36      Field36             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
37        SQLCHAR       0    25       ""     37      Field37             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
38        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     38      Field38             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
39        SQLCHAR       0    25       ""     39      Field39             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
40        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     40      Field40             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
41        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     41      Field41             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
42        SQLCHAR       0    3        ""     42      Field42             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
43        SQLCHAR       0    12       ""     43      Field43             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
44        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     44      Field44             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
45        SQLCHAR       0    12       ""     45      Field45             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
46        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     46      Field46             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
47        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     47      Field47             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
48        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     48      Field48             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
49        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     49      Field49             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
50        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     50      Field50             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
51        SQLCHAR       0    10       ""     51      Field51             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
52        SQLCHAR       0    3        ""     52      Field52             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
53        SQLCHAR       0    2        ""     53      Field53             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
54        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     54      Field54             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
55        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     55      Field55             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
56        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     56      Field56             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
57        SQLCHAR       0    14       ""     57      Field57             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
58        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     58      Field58             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
59        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     59      Field59             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
60        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     60      Field60             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
61        SQLCHAR       0    4        ""     61      Field61             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
62        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     62      Field62             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
63        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     63      Field63             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
64        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     64      Field64             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
65        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     65      Field65             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
66        SQLCHAR       0    3        ""     66      Field66             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
67        SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     67      Field67             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
68        SQLCHAR       0    3        ""     68      Field68             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
69        SQLCHAR       0    35       ""     69      Field69             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
70        SQLCHAR       0    30       ""     70      Field70             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
71        SQLCHAR       0    25       ""     71      Field71             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
72        SQLCHAR       0    20       ""     72      Field72             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
73        SQLCHAR       0    2        ""     73      Field73             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
74        SQLCHAR       0    9        ""     74      Field74             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
75        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     75      Field75             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
76        SQLCHAR       0    20       ""     76      Field76             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
77        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     77      Field77             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
78        SQLCHAR       0    20       ""     78      Field78             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
79        SQLCHAR       0    6        ""     79      Field79             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
80        SQLCHAR       0    9        ""     80      Field80             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
81        SQLCHAR       0    12       ""     81      Field81             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
82        SQLCHAR       0    10       ""     82      Field82             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
83        SQLCHAR       0    10       ""     83      Field83             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
84        SQLCHAR       0    50       ""     84      Field84             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
85        SQLCHAR       0    25       ""     85      Field85             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
86        SQLCHAR       0    25       ""     86      Field86             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
87        SQLCHAR       0    40       ""     87      Field87             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
88        SQLCHAR       0    40       ""     88      Field88             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
89        SQLCHAR       0    40       ""     89      Field89             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
90        SQLCHAR       0    30       ""     90      Field90             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
91        SQLCHAR       0    20       ""     91      Field91             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
92        SQLCHAR       0    15       ""     92      Field92             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
93        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     93      Field93             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
94        SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     94      Field94             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
95        SQLCHAR       0    20       ""     95      Field95             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
96        SQLCHAR       0    10       ""     96      Field96             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
97        SQLCHAR       0    20       ""     97      Field97             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
98        SQLCHAR       0    20       ""     98      Field98             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
99        SQLCHAR       0    2        ""     99      Field99             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
100       SQLCHAR       0    60       ""     100     Field100            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
101       SQLCHAR       0    9        ""     101     Field101            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
102       SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     102     Field102            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
103       SQLCHAR       0    200      ""     103     Field103            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
104       SQLCHAR       0    20       ""     104     Field104            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
105       SQLCHAR       0    2        ""     105     Field105            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
106       SQLCHAR       0    2        ""     106     Field106            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
107       SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     107     Field107            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
108       SQLCHAR       0    2        ""     108     Field108            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
109       SQLCHAR       0    8        ""     109     Field109            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
110       SQLCHAR       0    2        ""     110     Field110            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
111       SQLCHAR       0    2        ""     111     Field111            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
112       SQLCHAR       0    2        ""     112     Field112            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
113       SQLCHAR       0    2        ""     113     Field113            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
114       SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     114     Field114            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
115       SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     115     Field115            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
116       SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     116     Field116            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
117       SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     117     Field117            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
118       SQLCHAR       0    1        ""     118     Field118            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
119       SQLCHAR       0    20       ""     119     Field119            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
120       SQLCHAR       0    4        ""     120     Field120            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
121       SQLCHAR       0    4        ""     121     Field121            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
122       SQLCHAR       0    2        ""     122     Field122            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
123       SQLCHAR       0    4179     "\r\n" 0       ExtraFiller         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: This is *NOT* BCP, it is `BULK INSERT`.  Please do not confuse them, though similar, they are completely separate facilities.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I was actually trying both with the same results...wasn't clear enough in the question.  Added the bcp syntax I was using as well...

Comment: Are the fields which are missing in the file 'nullable' in the schema?

Comment: Yes, the fields for the missing data are nullable in the schema.

Comment: With *bcp* you could try the `/b 1` to specify a batch size of one.  That way the incomplete records fail, but don't affect any other records

Comment: I did try changing batch size, but still end up with 39 out of 42 records imported.  What I find confusing is that the 3 incomplete records are not causing the process to fail.  For some reason, it appears that BCP and BULK INSERT are glossing over the incomplete records...they are in no way imported into the table...just ignored it would seem...

Comment: There is probably a threshold number of errors that BCP will accept without failing, and 3 records is below the threshold.  I know Sybase BCP can work this way, so MS BCP probably has a similar feature.

Comment: It does. I believe the default is 10.  I did use the -m switch to set max errors = 0 (MAXERRORS = 0 in BULK INSERT), though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that BCP and BULK INSERT see the CRLF on the incomplete records as nothing more than values and don't recognize it as ending the row, which leads to the following row being consumed as part of the incomplete record. For a more complete explanation please see the answer on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d854554a-6e9a-4830-b2eb-f2f36ad8ecb5/bcp-and-bulk-insert-ignoring-incomplete-records-in-fixed-width-flat-file?forum=transactsql)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by specifying an error file. This causes bcp to create a little report with error row(s). After that your program can check if this error file contains any characters.

For Windows batch the code is as follows:

```
SET "ERRORFILE=C:\mytable.err"
TYPE NUL>%ERRORFILE%
bcp %DATABASENAME%.dbo.%DESTTABLE% IN %INPUTFILE% -f %FORMATFILE% -e "%ERRORFILE%" -S "%DBSERVER%" -U "%USERNAME%" -P "%PASSWORD%"
SET "SIZE=0"
FOR /f %%i IN ("%ERROR_FILE%") DO SET SIZE=%%~zi
IF %SIZE% GTR 0 (
  echo "import file contains error(s)."
  GOTO ERROR_HANDLER
)
```